# Is it possible and allowed to create lightweight "virtual" Apps?

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, app-store, google-play

Use case:
We have a container App which comes without the needed content preinstalled.
Only after installing the App, users choose which items they want to install. The items here are "city packs", that is data for rendering maps, routing offline etc.

It would be very attractive for several reasons to be able to create Appstore entries for specific cities. However we don't want to get into a mess by really duplicating the App (maintenance overhead, fragmentation, potentiall confusing for users).

That's why I was thinking about something like this:
The additional Appstore entries install a minimal App (I'll name it *client App*) which essentially just launches the main App with some parameters. On Android that should be possible with Intents, on iOS with custom URL schemes.
Since I don't know of any App using that approach, I wonder if they exist and if it's possible.

There are however 2 potential issues I see with that approach:

- If the main App isn't installed when one of the client Apps wants to launch it, the client App can still open the App page in the Appstore. At that point however the client App will lose control and I guess will not be able to have the main App launched with a parameter set. Is that correct?
- Would Apple accept such an App?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want to do is possible, but with my experience with Apple it is unlikely that they'd be happy with many different parts of the app being separate... I may be wrong, but that's how I think it'll go...
Have you thought about using in-app purchases? Even if the packs are free i'm sure you can set the cost to 0 and have the data download then?

Comment: The App already uses in-app purchase functionality. That doesn't solve what we want here.